# CSS Overflow property not working in iPad

Tags: ipad, css

I am designing some html pages for iPad. While trying out css overflow property like yscroll, auto. The scroll bar is not appearing in iPad and also the content not getting scroll. I tried in ipad simulator as well as in device. Is there any other way to achieve this property. Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are *no* scrollbars in any of the iPhone OS. Use 2 fingers to scroll. This is the expected gesture and will unlikely be changed.

Comment: one finger scrolling is widely used on all ios devices and it seems it'll make it into ios5's webkit too. look for "-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch"

Comment: Ya pretty sure you scroll with one finger

Answer (score 0):

make sure your body and divs have not a

```
 position:fixed
```

else scrolling would not work.