# Problems with div vertical scrollbars on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, html, scroll

When a user perform a search on my website I want to show the result in a small div with vertical scrollbars instead of that the user need to scroll the full page. That works perfect in all browsers BUT I get problems on the iPad. I can see that the search result doesn't fit into the div but no scroll bar is showing up on the iPad. Also when I try to scroll inside the div the full page is scrolled instead. Is there a solution to get this working?

HTML AND CSS:

```
<div class="searchResult">
    //Here I show the search result
</div>

div.searchResult
{
    height: 540px;
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I believe the answer is that you cannot scroll unless you use the two-finger methods. However if you look at the last link, there is a workaround.

Issues:
[CSS Overflow property not working in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183644)
http://www.webmanwalking.org/library/experiments/dsp_frames_outer_document.html

Workaround:
http://cubiq.org/scrolling-div-on-iphone-ipod-touch

Comment: The last link is dead, please don't rely on external sources for answers on SO.

Answer (score 2):

[iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com) is the jQuery plugin that tahdhaze09 mentioned. And to be more specific:

> iScroll is evolving and adding many new features to the basic
>   scrolling functionality. If all you need is the plain old scroller for
>   mobile webkit, you should really use `iscroll-lite.js` instead.

`iscroll-lite.js` is part of the iScroll package. It looks as if it will solve the one-finger scroll problem quite nicely.

Answer (score -1):

For some odd reason changing the div to a span works on an iPad.